# Spring Annotation Lazy Load

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, spring-annotations, spring-scheduled

Currently working on spring 3.2.3. We have developed one API application with this for 2 years now. It was working good. But as bean classes are increases there was exception about Circular dependency. So we have resolved that with changing default-lazy-init="true" in application-context.xml. But that lead to another challenge about @Scheduled is not working at all.

**Note** : Our application uses spring annotation so beans are not declared in xml file.
Below is my code for reference :

applicationContext.xml

```
<beans default-lazy-init="true" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans">
```

Service class

```
@Service("notificationService")
public class NotificationService{

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 09 11 * * *")
    @Async
    public void sampleNotificaton(){

    }
}
```

Try to add @Lazy(false) at service level but circular dependency exception still occur.

Appreciate your suggestion.
Thanks.

Comment: I have Same Problem But Not Found Any Solution??

Comment: I would try to resolve circular dependency in the first place. That is big design smell and some DI containers doesn't allow it at all.

Comment: Did you try `@EnableScheduling` annotation?

Comment: Thanks for your response @luboskrnac. Yes I tried EnableScheduling but still got issue. Yes I agree we should resolve circular depedency, but at this stage it takes more time to do that so we are avoiding that.

Answer (score 1):

As we have constraints not to break circular dependency (which is mostly very easy to solve BTW), I would try trick where, scheduling annotation would be extracted into separate bean:

```
@Component
public class NotificationScheduler {
    @Autowired //I prefer contructor injection, but field injection might be needed in this case because or circular dependency 
    private NotificationService notificationService;

    @Scheduled(cron = "0 09 11 * * *")
    public void sampleScheduling() {
        notificationService.sampleNotification();
    }
}

@Service("notificationService")
public class NotificationService{

    @Async
    public void sampleNotificaton(){

    }
}
```